# How to enable native Edit & Continue in VS 2015 after upgrade?

Tags: debugging, native, visual-studio-2015

How to enable native Edit & Continue in VS 2015 after upgrade (or a clean installation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a clean installation the Edit and Continue should be enabled by default.

If you have upgraded from a previous version, you will need to set all three of the following in your projects Property Page:

> 1. Under C/C++ -> General, set the "Debug Information Format" to
>      “Program Database for Edit and Continue (/ZI)”
> 2. Under the Linker -> General, set "Enable Incremental Linking" to
>      “Yes (/INCREMENTAL)”.
> 3. Under Debug -> General, (under the "Enable Edit and Continue”)
>      enable the "Native Edit and Continue"

Answer (score 2):

The Edit & Continue option has been moved to Tools==> Option==> Debugging. Below is the screenshot,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe it may be connected with default linker options that are not compatible with EnC. You can find some helpful information in this answer [How to ensure that the /EDITANDCONTINUE directive is not ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893621/how-to-ensure-that-the-editandcontinue-directive-is-not-ignored/38796524#38796524)