# Ignore changes and continue not behaving the same in VS15 as VS13

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2015

What happens in `VSC15` is a filename[stale].cpp is created and stepped through instead of the main edited file. This wouldn't be a problem except it not longer allows me to see any of the values of any variable when I mouse over or watch it making live debugging significantly less useful for me.

What used to happen is you'd be stepping through and the yellow cursor would just be some amount of lines off of where it actually was based on the compiled version of the file. I could still see all values so long as they were in memory.

Is there any way to get this functionality back? As it stands now I need to completely restart the app every time I make a change (frequently) if I want to still see any valuable debugging info.

[Edit and Continue is also arguably not a solution.. Wish it were.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36893621/1666510)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the behavior you're looking for (make changes to your source but not use Edit and Continue) by disabling the debugger option Debug > Options > Enable Native Edit and Continue.

Having this option disabled won't bring up the "Edits were made that could be applied..." dialog, but will instead silently ignore your edit and not go into any stale code.

I've answered your linked question, so I hope Edit and Continue is a solution :)

-Ramkumar,
Visual Studio Debugger